# Mid 80s movie about 3 mute aliens and telepathic woman

Tags: aliens, telepathy, story-identification

In the early to mid 80s, HBO aired a movie about 3 mute aliens (played by children looking bald and tan). They're helped by a male and female protagonist, and the aliens can communicate with the woman telepathically - I remember a scene where the woman is connected to an EKG showing why she might be able to do this. The feds (natch) are after them, and I think one of the aliens gets shot near the end. The film had a crazy synth/electronic score.

Sound familiar to anyone who knows the title?

Comment: EKG is heartbeats.  EEG is branwaves.

Answer (score 4):

"Wavelength" (1983)?

Here is the plot summary from IMDb.

> "Two young lovers learn that a small group of child-like space aliens
>   are marooned on Earth and are being held prisoner at a top secret
>   military facility. The couple then decide to liberate the
>   extraterrestrial castaways and help them make a rendezvous with a
>   rescue ship sent from the alien home planet."

It had the same plot as in your description. It has three bald aliens with 'tanned' skin who don't talk but communicate with the female lead through telepathy. The score is by Tangerine Dream. The entire movie is currently on YouTube and is posted below.