# What is the name of a movie from the 70s or 80s that had three aliens called Alpha, Beta, and Gamma?

Tags: story-identification, movie

The three were short, bald, and looked like children.

One of them was dissected which made a girl (who could hear their thoughts along with an old man) scream as if she were feeling it herself.

All doctors present at autopsy mysteriously died.

Aliens were kept inside a mountain lab.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SF&F - please take the [Tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) and see if there are any other details that you can think of that may help us identify the movie for you.  The more details you can add the better the chances are we can help :)

Comment: Likely a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184082/mid-80s-movie-about-3-mute-aliens-and-telepathic-woman

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*Wavelength*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086571/) from 1983?

> "Two young lovers learn that a small group of child-like space aliens *[codenamed Beta, Delta and Gamma]* are marooned on Earth and are being held prisoner at a top secret military facility. The couple then decide to liberate the extraterrestrial castaways and help them make a rendezvous with a rescue ship sent from the alien home planet."