# '80s sci-fi miniseries where bald, humanoid aliens crashed on Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

I vaguely remember this miniseries (or possibly TV movie) where aliens crashed on Earth. I recall them being bald and humanoid, and there were images of their written and spoken language. Not Alien Nation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this question by looking at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), then [edit]ing it to include any further details that come to mind. The more info you can provide, the better the chances that someone will be able to ID this for you.

Comment: Wavelength? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/184100/20774

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/scifi/comments/vaudlo/trying_to_remember_this_80s_scifi_miniseries/ -- same user on Reddit?

Comment: ^ are you the OP of the above Reddit post? If no, [you need to credit it in your post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) as this seems to be essentially the same question copied from there. If yes, then it's still useful to link the posts together (using exactly the same text in both questions is a giveaway, the connection is only a Google search away even without a link). From the Reddit post, it seems like the answer has been found? Could make that a self-answer here too if you want (then these comments can be deleted as they'd serve no further value).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are thinking of Alien Nation.  It was a science fiction media franchise  where it start with the film Alien Nation and was then made into a television series that aired on Fox.  It was also made into a comic book series.  The aliens in Alien Nation where known as the Tenctonese.

Comment: "Not *Alien Nation*".

Comment: The person who asked the question specifically said it is not Alien Nation